# show more than 20 invoices in invoice report in Microsoft Dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Out of box invoice report shows only maximum of 20 invoices.Is there a way to show more invoices?Unable to do even using SSRS. It's critical for our customer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "Unable to do even using SSRS"? You should be able to download the report (rdl), modify it and then re-upload back to CRM

Comment: What is the exact name of the Invoice report you are using?  I'm assuming this is being printed while looking at one of the invoice views?

Answer (score 0):

Download rdl of report, open it in SQL Server Data Tools, modify query that retrieves information and upload it back to CRM.